# Location Button doesn't appear mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true)

Tags: android, google-maps, geolocation, location

I cannot find what I'm missing. But Location Button doesn't appear on my google map.

in Manifest:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>


<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="MyKey" />

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

and in java:

```
        @Override
        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
            mMap = googleMap;
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

     // My code always finish here, so do not show location....
***//  in this part always return -1***

                return;
            }
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);

        }
```

Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: have you resolved this problem? It sound like you haven't turn on your location service yet.

Comment: @TranHieu yes, this is the cause of problem, program stays here:  if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) { return;}

Comment: always returns -1

Answer (score 1):

```
mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(false);
```

you can access the location button

Comment: It could be that there is a view in front that is hiding the button?